# Creating scheduled task from command line using account name containing space character

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

For project purpose , I followed Technet documentation to create scheduled task using either absolute path referencing or a XML file.

It looks like this :

```
SchTasks /Create /XML "scheduledtaskfile.xml" /tn "scheduled task name" /RU USERNAME /RP USERPWD /F
```

I was wondering if there was any syntax to replace USERNAME with local administrator account name containing one ore more space character (USER NAME for example).

Comment: You mean the Windows command line.  It isn't DOS.

Comment: It is a DOS command without a doubt , calling the underlying system executable without specifiying the full path is what I called a shortcut command.

Comment: No.  If it were a DOS command, it would run on the DOS operating system, the most recent release of which was in September 2000 and which is currently used approximately nowhere.  This is a Windows command, running on the Windows operating system.  I *assure* you that DOS has never had a `schtasks` command!

Comment: I understood what you meant back then; thanks for clarification and sorry for mentionning Windows DOS in question title, it should have been Windows command line.

Comment: Have you tried `/RU "USER NAME"` ?  That's the most common syntax.